# Since surface tension and area are conjugate variables, is there a uncertainty relation between them? $\Delta \gamma \Delta A \geq \text{constant}$

Tags: heisenberg-uncertainty-principle, surface-tension

Since all conjugate variables have uncertainty relations like ;

$$ \Delta f \Delta t \geq \text{constant}$$

$$ \Delta \lambda \Delta x \geq \text{constant}$$

Etcetera, is there also a 'uncertainty relation' for the conjugate variables $\gamma$ and $A$

$$\Delta \gamma \Delta A \geq  \text{constant}$$

Would it have any interesting results?

Comment: in what way are they conjugate variables?

Comment: @ZeroTheHero They are [thermodynamic conjugate variables](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugate_variables_\(thermodynamics\)), i.e., an intensive–extensive pair whose units multiply to give energy. The question appears to be whether they are *also* uncertainty-principle conjugate variables (and perhaps whether the former implies the latter). I don’t see why this would be the case; “conjugate” simply means we encounter a pair of variables in a certain context. This doesn’t mean those contexts are all equivalent. However, perhaps I’m unaware of a connection.

Comment: @Chemomechanics well certainly $\Delta \lambda \Delta x$ does not have units of energy (it is dimensionless) and likewise for $\Delta f\Delta t$, so methinks it’s only a exhaustion of nomenclature to call $\gamma$ and $A$ “conjugate”.  There is no Poisson bracket relations or Fourier relation.

Comment: "Conjugate" means only "coupled." The nomenclature is fine; it's a question of the context in which the coupling occurs. $(\gamma,A)$ are conjugate in the context of the [fundamental thermodynamic relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_thermodynamic_relation), in which they appear as a term $\gamma\,dA$ when surface tension–area work is considered.

Comment: There are uncertainty relations in statistical mechanics see e.g. https://arxiv.org/abs/0910.2867v1 and https://arxiv.org/abs/1112.3485v2 . But these are of course conceptually different from the ones in Quantum Mechanics.

Comment: @AlmostClueless thank you for those nice papers. very interesting